# Postgres SQL in Rails distinct, ordering on created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Baffled on this but I want to have this in rails syntax (seeing as I am using the Impressionist gem for audit purposes - I want the last 10 viewed items for a user - like a last viewed list)

This works as pure sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (unique_value) unique_value, created_at FROM impressions  WHERE user_id='2' ORDER BY unique_value, created_at  DESC LIMIT(10);
```

I cant really find the "rails way" to do this using PostGres

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work

```
Impressions.select(:unique_value).distinct.where(:user_id => '2').order(unique_value: :asc, created_at: :desc).limit(10)
```

Use [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to find more.

Comment: `created_at` needs to be selected as well.

Comment: Correct Jiří Pospíšil. It doesnt allow it to be sorted on a column not selected by the distinct